# FastAPI how to allow endpoint access for specific IP only?

Tags: fastapi

How to limit endpoint access only to specific IPs with FastAPI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FastAPI provides a [TrustedHostMiddleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#trustedhostmiddleware) that:

> Enforces that all incoming requests have a correctly set Host header, in order to guard against HTTP Host Header attacks.
>
> ```
> from fastapi import FastAPI
> from fastapi.middleware.trustedhost import TrustedHostMiddleware
>
> app = FastAPI()
>
> app.add_middleware(
>     TrustedHostMiddleware, allowed_hosts=["example.com","*.example.com"] 
> )
>
>
> @app.get("/")
> async def main():
>     return {"message": "Hello World"}
> ```
>
> The following arguments are supported:
>
> - `allowed_hosts` - A list of domain names that should be allowed as hostnames. Wildcard domains such as `*.example.com` are supported for
>   matching subdomains to allow any hostname either use
>   `allowed_hosts=["*"]` or omit the middleware.
>
> If an incoming request does not validate correctly then a 400 response
> will be sent.

Another solution would be to compose an IP whitelist for your deployment medium (ex: k8).

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer makes use of the [TrustedHostMiddleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#trustedhostmiddleware) but that can be easily spoofed using a reverse proxy, i.e. using NGINX or using any other technique. In my opinion, validating IP address in a [custom middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) is more secure:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


app = FastAPI()

# Whitelisted IPs
WHITELISTED_IPS = []

@app.middleware('http')
async def validate_ip(request: Request, call_next):
    # Get client IP
    ip = str(request.client.host)
    
    # Check if IP is allowed
    if ip not in WHITELISTED_IPS:
        data = {
            'message': f'IP {ip} is not allowed to access this resource.'
        }
        return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, content=data)

    # Proceed if IP is allowed
    return await call_next(request)
```

I'd maintain a list of whitelisted IPs and then I'd compare the client IP to the list and will return a `400 Bad Request` error if the IP is not in the whitelisted IPs list.

Comment: Note that if you're running behind a reverse proxy, `request.client.host` will always be the IP of the reverse proxy. In this case you need to get the client's IP from the `X-Forwarded-For` header. There's [uvicorn's `ProxyHeaderMiddleware`](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py), which does exactly that, given a list of trusted ips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ufw

`sudo ufw allow from IP proto tcp to any port PORT`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).