# Whitelist web application for API access without API key

Tags: rest, next.js, fastapi, api-key, websecurity

We're developing a web application (SPA) consisting of the following parts:

1. NextJS container
2. Django backend for user management
3. Data API (FastAPI) protected with API keys, for which we also provide 3rd party access

The NextJS container uses an API key to access the data API. We don't want to expose the API key to the client (browser), so the browser sends the API requests to the NextJS container, which then relays it to the data API, see [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/12/protect-api-key-production-nextjs-api-route/). This seems secure, but is more complicated and slower than sending requests from the browser to the data API directly.

I'm wondering if it's possible to whitelist the web application in the data API, so that the client (browser) can call the data API directly without API key, but 3rd parties can't. FastAPI provides a [TrustedHostMiddleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#trustedhostmiddleware), but it's insecure because it's possible to spoof the host header. It has been suggested to [whitelist IPs instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867814/fastapi-how-to-allow-endpoint-access-for-specific-ip-only), but we don't have a dedicated IP for our web application. I looked into using the referer header, but it's not available in the FastAPI request object for some reason (I suspect some config problem in our hosting). Also, the referer header could be spoofed as well.

Is there even a safe way to whitelist our web application for data API access, or do we need to relay the request via NextJS container and use an API key?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but aren't the API requests sent from the browser? What are you hoping to whitelist exactly?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, API requests are sent from the browser, but we can't send them to the data API directly, because the API key would be revealed in the request header. Instead, we currently send them to the NextJS container without API key, and the container relays them to the data API with added API key. Whitelisting would allow us to get rid of this relay.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. What I didn't get is what would you want to whitelist to make that happen, as each request will be coming from different clients? Without the relay from the Next.js server, each request will come from the browser directly.

Comment: I'd like to whitelist the domain where the web application is running. The goal is that only our web application can use the data API without API key, but no one else. But maybe that's just not possible in a secure way, we researched quite a bit by now...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there even a safe way to whitelist our web application for data API
> access,

No, you need in all case an Authentication mechanism, something before the backend that check if the client is an authorize client.

The simplest pattern is using the NextJS container as the proxy. Proxy that have an api-key to call the backend ( what you are currently doing ).

There is many way to implement a secured proxy for a backend, but this authentication logic should not be inside the backend but in a separate service ( like envoy , nginx ... )